# Recognizing emerging topic within ongoing topic

Tags: nlp, data-cleaning, twitter

I have been collecting a large amount of tweets from Twitter for a few weeks related to a series of specific keywords, and would like to address a specific problem. Say I collected all tweets mentioning the word "Monsters", and it averaged about 50k tweets a day, but this week, James Blunt released a new song "Monsters" which becomes a particular hit and that amount increases to maybe 80k. What would be a good approach to help distinguish between the usual usages of the word "Monsters" and the new tweets that are presumably related to James Blunt? I would imagine there are quite a few options, so any ideas would be much appreciated.